# Configure Modal Dialog

Tags: angular, dialog, popup, modal-dialog

I have an issue configuring a modal dialog in ***angular 2***

I am trying to delete a user and I want to have buttons like 'Yes' and 'No'.
Here is a shortcut of the modal.
[image]

This is the function:

```
 public deleteUser(i: number) {
    this.modal.alert().size('lg')
      .title('A simple Alert style modal window')
      .body(`
            <h4>Are you sure you want to delete the user?</h4>`)
      .open();

  }
```

For modal component I am using Modal from angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap
<<`import { Modal } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap'`;>>

Could someone tell me how to remove the 'Ok' button and Adding the 'Yes' and 'No' buttons, please?

Thank you

Comment: It does not seem to be supported in this library, you'll have to hack a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen the **wrong modal** method, `alert()` from the [Bootstrap plugin](http://shlomiassaf.github.io/angular2-modal/#/bootstrap-demo) offered by [Angular 2 Modal](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal).

Use the `.confirm()` modal instead.

Check the [modal code Generator](http://shlomiassaf.github.io/angular2-modal/#/bootstrap-demo/customizeModals).

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom modal component like:

```
export class CustomModalContext extends BSModalContext {
  yesCallback: () => Promise<any>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button  class="close" type="button" (click)="dialog.close()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-body">
            <h4>Are you sure you want to delete the user?</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="yes()">Yes</button>
            <button class="btn" (click)="dialog.close()">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>`
})
export class CustomModal implements CloseGuard, ModalComponent<CustomModalContext> {
  context: CustomModalContext;

  constructor(public dialog: DialogRef<CustomModalContext>) {
    this.context = dialog.context;
    dialog.setCloseGuard(this);
  }

  yes() {
    this.context.yesCallback()
      .then(() => this.dialog.close())
  }

  beforeDismiss(): boolean {
    return true; // prevent closing modal by using Esc
  }
}
```

Then add it to `declarations` and `entryComponents` of your `@NgModule` metadata

```
  declarations: [ App, CustomModal ],
  entryComponents: [CustomModal],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And use it as follows

```
deleteUser() {
   return this.modal.open(CustomModal,
       overlayConfigFactory({
           yesCallback: () => {
               alert('Deleting');
               return Promise.resolve(null)
           }
       }, BSModalContext));
 }
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/eNzbi3HATjHGKVZcFiDC?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.footerClass('no-display')` before your `open()`, and define this CSS class like so :

```
no-display {
    display: none;
}
```